# Вызов функции из другого файла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть общий файл (*main.js*) для всех скриптов, в нём прописана функция для кнопки "наверх":

```
function button_top_right (n) {
    var top_button = $("#main").offset().top;
    $("#top_right").hide();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > top_button + n) {
            $('#top_right').fadeIn().addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            $('#top_right').fadeOut();
        }
    });
};
button_top_right (1500);
```

Для одной страницы мне надо вызвать эту функцию с другим параметром `n`.
Добавляю скрипт на эту страницу:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    button_top_right (100);
});
```

Скрипт не срабатывает с ошибкой:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: button_top_right is not defined

*main.js* подгружается раньше, чем вызов функции.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Кстати, если вы вызовете-таки эту функцию дважды на странице, то у вас будет висеть уже два обработчика `scroll` для `window`. Вряд ли это чем-то хорошим кончится.

Comment: А объявление этой функции, случаем, не находится ли внутри другого `document.ready`?

Comment: @Regent, вы правы. Если вынести функцию за пределы document.ready, то появится другая закономерная ошибка: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null`. Да и два обработчика одновременно плохая идея, сразу не подумала об этом.

Comment: По поводу `top of null`: достаточно `button_top_right (1500);` оставить внутри `document.ready`, а функцию вынести из него. В таком случае и функция будет везде доступна, и первый вызов будет своевременно.

Comment: По поводу двух вызовов: можно при вызове функции удалять предыдущий обработчик (`.off('scroll')`), однако всегда ли в нужном порядке будут происходить вызовы - не знаю.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Добавила вот такой код: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).off('scroll');
    button_top_right (300);
});`  Работает.

Comment: На здоровье. Если вопрос исчерпан, либо его можно просто удалить, либо я могу попытаться скомпоновать комментарии в ответ.

Comment: @Regent, предлагаю оформить ответ.

Comment: @Regent, давайте оставим для истории

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Когда функция объявлена внутри `document.ready`, обратиться к ней извне не получится. Достаточно вынести саму функцию, а её вызовы оставить внутри `document.ready`:

```
function button_top_right(n) {
    ...
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    button_top_right(1500);
});
```

Так как внутри функции `button_top_right` при каждом вызове функции добавляется обработчик события `scroll` для `window`, имеет смысл убирать предыдущий обработчик либо перед вызовом функции, либо внутри функции перед добавлением нового:

```
$(window).off("scroll").on("scroll", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Лучший, обнял, поднял!!